# Why my static paste doesn't work anymore?

Tags: github, flask, static, vercel

I'm having an issue with uploading my portifolio

```
  /usr/bin/git submodule sync --recursive
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --depth=1 --recursive
  Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'api/static' in .gitmodules
  Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

I'm using vercel to load a repositorie from github, and the github is saing that issue, whats cause that my website doesn't load the past static what is where my css arquives it is, so only loading the html, so I dont know what to do from here, I can give more information if you ask me, I just want to resolve this

Resolve the problem from github doesn´t load the static arquive for vercel use